# Different and inconsistent line heights in NSTextView and CATextLayer

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

I am working on creating a canvas-like interface where text box objects can be created and edited. All drawing is handled through CALayers, but I am using invisible NSTextViews for event handling when a text box is being actively edited. For accurate event capture, I need the lines of text in the NSTextView and CATextLayer to be laid out identically (particularly for multi-line text boxes).

The problem is that NSTextView and CATextLayer seem to render text slightly differently, giving them different line heights. This varies by font; sometimes NSTextView comes up shorter, sometimes longer. The black text below is in an NSTextView, while the blue is a CATextLayer. Helvetica Neue is slightly misaligned as lines accumulate, while Helvetica is quite overtly misaligned from the start.

[image]

I have no idea where the difference comes from, especially since the effect is so unpredictable. Is there a way to account for the line height difference, or, is there a better way to relay events captured from an NSTextView to/from a CATextLayer?

Swift playground code (macOS 10.12.1, Xcode 7.1.1; though the issue has existed since at least 10.11):

```
// Tested fonts:
// Andale Mono - slight misalignment
// Courier - extreme misalignment
// Courier New - small misalignment
// Helvetica - large misalignment
// Helvetica Neue - no (?) misalignment

import Cocoa

// setup
var str = "Text\nText\nText\nText\nText\nText\nText\nText\nText"
var theFont = CTFontCreateWithName("Helvetica Neue", 20, nil)
var parentView:NSView = NSView(frame: NSRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)))

// create basic NSTextView
var textView:NSTextView = NSTextView(frame: NSRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 300)))
textView.string = str
textView.font = theFont
parentView.addSubview(textView)

// create what SHOULD be an equivalent CATextLayer
var layerView:NSView = NSView(frame: NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 300)))
layerView.wantsLayer = true
var textLayer = CATextLayer()
textLayer.contentsScale = 2
textLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 1, alpha: 1).CGColor
textLayer.foregroundColor = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0.6, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1).CGColor
textLayer.string = str
textLayer.font = CTFontCopyFullName(theFont)
textLayer.fontSize = CTFontGetSize(theFont)
layerView.layer = textLayer
parentView.addSubview(layerView)

// final display
parentView
```